# Show various content on radio select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, tabs, radio-button

I am trying to hide and show different div's depending on which radio you select. Unfortunately I could not come up with working solution so far. Here is my starting code http://jsbin.com/edokef/1/edit

Maybe someone could suggest how to achieve that? I was thinking about getting the index of each radio but each radio is inside separate div wrap and in that case the index is always 0.

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo: http://jsbin.com/edokef/7/edit

Code:

```
options.click(function(){
      var id = "opt" + $(this).val();
      $(".optDivs").hide();
      $("#" + id).show();

    });
```

Plus, each div that should be shown has a class now (`optDivs`)

Comment: your version is so short and simple. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not providing You with a full solution.

1) Why do You want to use indexes? Every radio has a value. Use that instead.

2) "to hide and show different div's depending on which radio you select" sounds to me at least like one to many relationship. I recommend using publisher/subscriber for this task. There are many usable implementations of this pattern eg. https://github.com/federico-lox/pubsub.js

PS Try to avoid pubsub implementations based on jQuery (they manipulate on DOM and and are kinda slow)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show or hide based on div based on radio button

```
  var options = $('#options').find('input');

  options.click(function(){

   $("#"+$(this).parent().attr('class')).toggle();

  });

})();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/edokef/10/edit)

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you

```
$(function(){

  (function(){

  var options = $('#options').find('input');

    options.click(function(){
         if($(this).is(':checked'))
         {

          $('#' + $(this).parent().attr('class')).show();
         }
                  else
                  {
                  $('#' + $(this).parent().attr('class')).hide();
                  }

    });

  })();

  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/edokef/5/edit)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
  <script>
  $(function(){

  (function(){

  var options = $('#options').find('input');

    $(options).click(function(){

      $('#opt1, #opt2, #opt3').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).parent().attr('class')).show();

    });

  })();

  });
  </script>
```